# MOSS 2007: Programmatically add a webzone inside of a webzone

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a page that I want to heavily customize. On that page, I have a web part that will tab all of the web parts inside of that webzone, except I want to simply tab two web parts that will be to the right of another web part inside the same webzone.

I tried copy / pasting `<ZoneTemplate> </ZoneTemplate>` into the source code via SharePoint Designer, but it won't save saying that the page is 'invalid.' I know the page is based off of a specific schema, but has anyone gotten around this?

Comment: You can't nest Web Part Zones. ASP.NET doesn't allow it, not just a SharePoint thing.

Comment: Is there a better tabbing solution that is more customizable then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a Web Part Zone for each set of Web Parts you want to include in a tab set with Easy Tabs. You can easily add as many Web Part Zones as you want in SharePoint Designer and even custimize their containing markup.

If you want to work a little harder but have more flexibility you could turn to jQueryUI.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Easy Tabs from Path2SharePoint.

http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/pages/easyTabs.aspx

Comment: I am using Easy Tabs, and it rolls up everything in the container web zone. I suppose I could just edit the source code to only go up to a div that I around the specified web parts... but there has got to be an easier way.